# rails simple_form inline_label and radio_buttons not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In my rails 4.0.0 `simple_form`, I find that adding `inline_label` to a boolean input is ignored and adding `as: radio_buttons` produces this error:

```
No input found for radio_buttons
```

Here is my form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for (@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :user_name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.input :office_administrator, as: :radio_buttons %>
  <%= f.input :bill_payer, inline_label: 'Can pay bills?' %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the generator again and it fixed the issue.

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `gem 'simple_form'` in you Gemfile but you need to use it from master branch for now since SimpleForm with Rails 4 support wasn't released yet:

`gem 'simple_form', github: 'plataformatec/simple_form'`

Comment: It made no difference, the label is still displayed above the checkbox and no custom label is visible at all. inline-label is simply ignored.

Comment: Yes, radio buttons now work. I have decided better to go with the flow and render boolean as checkbox but its imperative that labels be inline for mobile use.

Comment: I tried form-inline which works but the form layout is all compressed and ugly.

Comment: Yes, these are for booleans. I really wish I could find a way to make them work!

Comment: Apparently this won't work with fluid layouts - I am using bootstrap responsive.

Comment: In this application, <%= simple_form_for @user, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %> is not working (horizontal) but similar code in another application works fine.